# How to pass arguments in alert message - aspx page alert

Tags: asp.net

I would like to pass arguments in an alert message.

```
var bankCodeName = "ABC";
alert("<%= Common.GetResourceText("BankCodeSearch_SearchByBranchAlert") %>", bankCodeName);
```

Comment: Is `Common.GetResourceText("BankCodeSearch_SearchByBranchAlert")` a code-behind method? Try searching for asp.net ajax 'page methods'.

Comment: Try this Snippet - `function customAlertBox(sBranch,sBankcodeName){ alert(sBranch+sBankcodename);}                                                                                
  var bankCodeName = "ABC";
customAlertBox("<%= Common.GetResourceText("BankCodeSearch_SearchByBranchAlert") %>", bankCodeName);`

Answer (score 1):

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class _Default: Page
    {
        private string clients;
        public string Clients { get { return clients; } }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clients = "test msg";
        }
    }
```

**Default.aspx**
you need to put your javascript code inside Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//your code
 </script>
```

tag so the Aspx renderer can understand the difference between HTML and Javascript code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var bankCodeName = "ABC";
        var client='<%= Clients %>';
       alert(bankCodeName+client);
        </script>
```

`var client='<%= Clients %>';` line saves your code behind variable value to JavaScript variable.